# Jquery search - What computes faster?

Tags: jquery, search

I am trying to always make my script logic compute as fast as possible.

```
$("ul").prepend( $("ul li:last") );
```

vs

```
$("ul").prepend( $(this).find("li:last") );
```

Basically, what is the fastest way to bring the last list element to the front of the list?

Comment: The second one doesn't do what you expect. `this` doesn't refer to the `ul` element.

Comment: Test it yourself and see! http://jsperf.com

Comment: What is `this` referring to?

Comment: Btw, have you tested this on multiple `<ul>`? Otherwise you definitely need an `.eq(0)` somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend doing it this way instead.

```
var $list = $("ul");
$list.prepend($list.children().last());
```

Otherwise you end up selecting the same element multiple times, which is something you want to avoid if you are concerned about performance.

---

**EDIT**: Per @Jack's comment below, he is right.  This will not work correctly when there are multiple `<ul>` elements on the page.  Something like this might work better.

```
$("ul").each(function(){
  var $thisList = $(this);
  $thisList.prepend($thisList.children().last());
});
```

Comment: http://jsperf.com/which-computes-faster

Comment: It should be mentioned that this (even though the question was leading) gives incorrect results when multiple `<ul>` elements are on the page; see also [here](http://jsbin.com/eqekes/3/).

Comment: I assumed it was just an example and he'd really be targeting the individual `ul` directly, but yeah, I'm guilty of copy/pasting into jsperf while eating a sandwich.

Answer (score 1):

If you want fast, you wouldn't use jQuery:

```
void function(lists) {
  for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; ++i) {
    var children = lists[i].children;

    if (children.length > 1) {
      lists[i].insertBefore(children[children.length - 1], children[0]);
    }
  }
}(document.getElementsByTagName('ul'));
```

[**Benchmark**](http://jsperf.com/which-computes-faster)

Comment: Would this simply be faster because by using jQuery it is rendering it as javascript? I will create a benchmark for both of the supplied answers and comment the results back.

Comment: @ChessMaker There's already a [benchmark here](http://jsperf.com/which-computes-faster).

Comment: Crikey, I never knew it would be so overwhelming! I guess I need to revisit my jQuery modules and investigate better algorithms

Comment: @ChessMaker Yep, jQuery trades convenience for performance. Btw, you can only accept one answer; once you have 20 rep you can upvote other answers :)